# Solving $a_{n+1} = c_n a_n$ using generating functions

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I need to solve a recurrence relation of the form for $a_n$:

$$a_{n+1} = c_n a_n,\quad n\ge 0$$

where the constants $c_n$ and the initial condition $a_0$ are given. However I do not know the $c_n$ *a priori*, so I would like to write down a solution for $a_n$, in some form, that shows the dependence on $c_n$. I tried the generating function approach, but the only way I see here is to define *two* generating functions:

$$A(x) = \sum_{n\ge0}a_n x^n,\quad B(x) = \sum_{n\ge0}c_n a_n x^n$$

Then we have:

$$\frac{A(x) - a_0}{x} = B(x)$$

This does not get me very far, because I have *two* generating functions and only one equation. Is there a way to tackle this problem?

Comment: "I would like to write down a solution"... a solution of what?

Comment: Q1: What are the condition imposed on $c_n$?

Comment: $c_n$ is a constant?

Comment: @5xum I want to solve for the $a_n$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The $c_n$ are fixed numbers. The solution $a_n$ of the recurrence relation will of course depend on the values assigned to the $c_n$. My question is if we can find a way to write this relation, to obtain $a_n$ from $c_n$.

Comment: Is this any harder than $a_{n+1} = c_na_n = c_nc_{n-1}a_{n-1} = \cdots = (c_nc_{n-1}\cdots c_1c_0)a_0$?

Comment: @Neal To be honest, I was trying to find a minimal example of a more complicated problem I am trying to solve, without getting into too much detail. But I see I have oversimplified. I'll try my luck in another question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$a_{n+1}=c_{n}a_{n}$$
Devide by $\prod_{k=0}^{n}c_{k}$ to give
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}c_{k}}=\frac{a_{n}}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k}}$$
Let
$$\frac{a_{n}}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k}}=A_{n}$$
Then
$$A_{n+1}=A_{n}$$
Hence $A_{n}=A$, where $A$ is constant
$$A=\frac{a_{n}}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k}}$$
So
$$a_{n}=A\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{k}$$

Comment: why did you switch a and c? just for fun or there is a reason?

Comment: Sorry, I'll correct it. I've just misread the thing)

Comment: Wow, very nice! Damn, you didn't need generating functions.

Comment: Its exponential growth right?

Comment: Yes you right down $a_{n+1}=c_{n}a_{n}=(1+hb_{n})a_{n}$ and take the limit $h\rightarrow0$ to get the exponential of integral (i.e. it will be the solution of the first order ode). Moreover, if you add the inhomogeneous term, by the very same method the recurrence is solvable, and you will have the inhomogeneous term in the solution which will become an integrating factor sort of thing in the continuous limit

Comment: @KirylPesotski: It seems in your last line you represent $a_n$ by a product containing $a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Since
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}&=c_na_n\\
a_n&=c_{n-1}a_{n-1}\\
&\ \ \,\vdots\\
a_1&=c_0a_0
\end{align*}

multiplication of LHS and RHS gives
\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}a_k&=\left(\prod_{k=0}^n c_k\right)\left(\prod_{k=0}^na_k\right)
\end{align*}

> Given that $a_n\ne 0$ for $n\geq 0$ we can divide by $\prod_{k=1}^na_k$ and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> a_{n+1}=a_0\prod_{k=0}^nc_k\qquad\qquad n\geq 0
> \end{align*}